# Edit .doc or .docx file using php

Tags: php

I have to modify the uploaded .doc or .docx file in php. I googled but i only found how to read that. I want the word file as it is and put text at the bottom of that MS Word file at run time. How is this possible anyone know please reply or give me example script.

Thanks,

Answer (score 20):

I'm the developer of PHPWord. You can use the PHPWord_Template Class to open an existing DOCX File and then replace some text marks with your individual text.

Alternatively you can open the DOCX file with the ZipArchive extension and then read/write every xml File (document.xml, header.xml, footer.xml, ...) you want. This method is nothing else than the PHPWord_Template class. ;)

Comment: can I open the document for editing in the browser using PHPWord?

Comment: @UmairAyub you mean like Google Docs? No man, PHPWord is only for programmatically generating word documents. A browser-based word processor is kind of a big deal, you're not just gonna find a library that handles all of that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have same requirement for Edit **.doc** or **.docx** file using php and i have find solution for it.
And i have write post on It :: http://www.onlinecode.org/update-docx-file-using-php/

```
if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
{
    // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
    // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.

    $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
    $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);               

    $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');

    // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
    $message = str_replace("client_full_name",      "onlinecode org",       $message);
    $message = str_replace("client_email_address",  "ingo@onlinecode.org",  $message);
    $message = str_replace("date_today",            $timestamp,         $message);      
    $message = str_replace("client_website",        "www.onlinecode.org",   $message);      
    $message = str_replace("client_mobile_number",  "+1999999999",          $message);

    //Replace the content with the new content created above.
    $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
    $zip_val->close();
}
```

Comment: how to bold replaced text/word?

Answer (score 2):

You only replace the predefined variables.
In the following code

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
I also did this problem in phpword using the following code

```
 if(!file_exists('file/word.docx')){
  $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('demo.docx');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('name', 'Akbarali');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('time','13.02.2021');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('month', 'January');
  $templateProcessor->setValue('state','Uzbekistan');
  $templateProcessor->saveAs('file/word.docx');
}
```

This will change the words in the demo.docx file. The new file is then saved in the word.docx file folder.
you can define variables in the form of ${name} in the demo word file.
that is, ${name}, ${time}, ${month} and ${state}

Comment: how to bold replaced text/word?

Comment: Make your variables bold so that the entries you write should also be bold

Comment: How can we make bold / unbold condition wise?

Answer (score 2):

In this post we will show you How to update docx file using php, hear for How to update docx file using php we will give you demo and example for implement.
Hear we will show you how to Edit .doc or .docx file using php. Hear we use “client_full_name”, “client_email_address”, “date_today”, “client_website”, “client_mobile_number” in .doc or .docx files

```
    $template_file_name = 'template.docx';
 
$rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
$fileName = "results_" . $rand_no . ".docx";
 
$folder   = "results_";
$full_path = $folder . '/' . $fileName;
 
try
{
    if (!file_exists($folder))
    {
        mkdir($folder);
    }       
         
    //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
    copy($template_file_name, $full_path);
 
    // add calss Zip Archive
    $zip_val = new ZipArchive;
 
    //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
    if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
    {
        // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
        // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.
         
        $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
        $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);                
                     
        $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
         
        // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
        $message = str_replace("client_full_name",      "onlinecode org",       $message);
        $message = str_replace("client_email_address",  "ingo@onlinecode",  $message);
        $message = str_replace("date_today",            $timestamp,             $message);      
        $message = str_replace("client_website",        "www.onlinecode",   $message);      
        $message = str_replace("client_mobile_number",  "+1999999999",          $message);
         
        //Replace the content with the new content created above.
        $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
        $zip_val->close();
    }
}
catch (Exception $exc) 
{
    $error_message =  "Error creating the Word Document";
    var_dump($exc);
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution, without additionnal library. Thank you !

Comment: how to bold replaced text/word?

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers dont contain the full steps so here is what ive done:

Create your word document. With in this document anything you want to replace with PHPWORD mark it like this -> ${variable_name} so for example ${value1}

```
$file = "docs/input/word/source.docx";
$output_file = "docs/input/word/modified.docx";

$PHPWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate($file);
$document->setValue('value1', 'Enter Your Text Here');
$document->saveAs($output_file);
```

Comment: how to bold replaced text/word?