# MsWord WYSIWYG Editor for my Website

Tags: php, ms-word, wysiwyg

I want to make an website where user will be able to open various uploaded Ms-Word .doc or .docx files, edit them on the fly and then save them through any WYSIWYG MsWord-like editor. The interface should be very much similar to MsWord.

DO you have any Idea which editor I should use? FCKEditor, TinyMCE etc are editors but they can not open .doc or .docx files.

PLz help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369061/edit-doc-or-docx-file-using-php

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy task, your best off using a 3rd party like Google Docs to do this.

They have an API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/).

Answer (score 0):

All the online WYSIWYG editors supports mainly `HTML` and `RTF` formats.

Try a 3rd party API as suggested by @fire, Google.

Also you can go for SkyDrive API that can provide you an online MS Office interface.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7638882/803285) answer.